# Why qualified name error?

Tags: c++, templates

I'd just like to understand why compiler is giving this error and what needs to be changed? I am just playing around with C++11 code.

```
class test 
{
public:
    template<int N>
    bool foo() { return true;} 

    template<int N, int... Ns>
    struct table : table<N-1, N-1,Ns...> {};

    template<int... Ns>
    struct table<0,Ns...>
    {
        static constexpr bool(test::table<0,Ns...>::*fns[])() = {foo<Ns>...};
    };

    // below line gives the error

    template<int... Ns>
    constexpr bool (*test::table<0,Ns...>::fns[sizeof...(Ns)]) ();
};

int main()
{
}
```

The error is:

> error: invalid use of qualified-name test::table<0, Ns ...>::fns

Comment: There are so many problems with this code. For example, `foo` is a "`test::*`", not "`test::table<0, Ns...>::*`". And most of these problems have nothing to do with the one error you showed.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If by the second-to-last line you want to declare a member function of `test`, that member function must be given an unqualified name.

Comment: @JohnB, I think the OP is trying to define the static member `fns`. The definition is just not supposed to be inside a class.

Comment: Thanks for answers.  Very helpful to learn. One more question.  If I want to modify the definition and declaration of fns to be a 2d array how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

`test::table` may be a member template of `test`, but it doesn't have unqualified access to `test`'s member functions. This is what you are assuming here:

```c++
= {foo<Ns>...};
// ^^^
```

You to use a qualified-id for the pointer-to-member to be well-formed (i.e `&test::foo<Ns>`). Moreover, the "definition" of `fns` following the `table` specialization cannot go inside class scope. Static data member definitions go in *namespace scope*.

You also need to change `*test::table` to `test::*table` in this definition as the later correctly denotes a pointer to member. [@chris's example shows the correct code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a412f5890b55825).

---

You could also do away with the `table` template and use the built-in `std::index_sequence` tool if you have access to C++14.

```c++
#include <utility>

struct test {
    template<int>bool foo(){return true;}
    template<int...Is>
    static auto& make_foo_table(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
        using callable=bool(test::*)();
        using table=callable[sizeof...(Is)];
        return table{&test::foo<Is>...};
    }
    template<int N>
    constexpr static auto&make_foo_table(){
        return make_foos(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
    }
};
```